# push special elements of array of objects to another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping, javascript-objects

i have an large array of objects full of values and i have an empty array of objects as well, and i am willing to get every value from full array of objects (btw full array of objects has more keys than empty one) and push it to empty one like so:

```
/*empty one (array1):*/ [{foo: '', bar: '', thumbnail: ''}];

/*full one (array2):*/ [{foo_: 'blah', bar: 'blah',
                       thumbnail: '/photo', id: 'ad12dxa1', something: 'thing'},{foo_: 'blah1', bar: 'blah1',
                       thumbnail: '/photo1', id: 'ad12dxa12', something: 'thing1'}];
```

and i want to get only `foo_`, `bar` and `thumbnail` from array2 and insert them as `foo`, `bar` & `thumbnail` into array1 like: `foo` = `foo_` `bar`=`bar`, `thumbnail`= `thumbnail`

if answer will include both `for` loop and `array.every` method explanation it would be better.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a new array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with some [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring):

```js
const data = [
  {foo_: 'blah', bar: 'blah', thumbnail: '/photo', id: 'ad12dxa1', something: 'thing'},
  {foo_: 'blah1', bar: 'blah1', thumbnail: '/photo1', id: 'ad12dxa12', something: 'thing1'}
];
                                            
const result = data.map(({foo_:foo, bar, thumbnail}) => ({foo, bar, thumbnail}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your answer had a "run code snippet" button, which worked, until you started editing it. I'd recommend going back to the first version.

Comment: There it is again. Don't touch anything now.

Comment: this code is little obscure, can you add explanation what does `foo_:foo` and => means because you modified my code and your code has not any `foo` key and also i please use my code as an example

Comment: @iLiA I've added the links to the docs containing necessary information with simple examples. `=>` represents the [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: thank you @MohammadUsman, can you also provide `.every` and for loop anwer?

Comment: because in my actual array of object thumbnail is an array and i need to select only first element of it

Comment: @iLiA You can't use `.every()` to get the expected output. This purpose of this method is to check whether all array items passed the test implemented by its callback function. Further `for` loop is used to iterate over array items. As you mentioned that you wants to select first element only so there is no need to use `for` loop. You can select first item using `const first = arrayReference[0]`

Comment: I think you did not get what I mean. in this AoO const data = [
  `{foo_: 'blah', bar: 'blah', thumbnail: '/photo', id: 'ad12dxa1', something: 'thing'},
  {foo_: 'blah1', bar: 'blah1', thumbnail: '/photo1', id: 'ad12dxa12', something: 'thing1'}
];`  thumbnail key is actually an array and i need to select only first element from thumbnail and push it to new array

Comment: @iLiA You can use following variant of the above code e.g `=> ({foo, bar, thumbnail: thumbnail[0]}`

Comment: regardless i can not understand how it works Thank you LOL